# Prove that $\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{2x-2} + \sqrt{9-3x} < 3\sqrt{3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers

Prove that $\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{2x-2} + \sqrt{9-3x} < 3\sqrt{3}$ for x$\in\mathbb R$ and the square root exists. I observed that $1 \le x\le3$ and then i tried to raise the initial equation to the second power but nothing improved. Also, i am not sure if this is true, but if the equation holds for $x = 1$ and $x = 3$ then it must be true for all x in the interval.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: How is this related to number theory or irrational numbers?

Comment: *Hint:* The square root is a *concave* function.

Comment: In other words, 1) please pay attention to your tags so that they fit they question, and 2) the general case of Jensen's inequality applies here but for a concave function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the root-mean square inequality:

$$\frac{a+b+c}{3} ≤ \sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}}$$

for all real nonnegative $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 0):

What @Toby Mak said, where $$a=\sqrt{9x+18}$$ $$b=\sqrt{18x-18}$$ $$c=\sqrt{81-27x}$$

Comment: Doesen't it work for just$a=\sqrt{x+2}, b=\sqrt{2x-2},c=\sqrt{9-3x}$?

Comment: Exactly, it works as is because you can multiply both sides by $3$.